# Solving Mathematical logics, placing digits in third number from digits of first and second number

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, logic, business-logic

I have two numbers.

```
First Number is 2875 &
Second Number is 852145
```

Now I need a program which create third number.

```
Third Number will be 2885725145
```

The logic is

```
First digit of third number is first digit of first number.  
Second digit of third number is first digit of second number.  
Third digit of third number is second digit of first number.  
Fourth digit of third number is second digit of second number;
```

so on.

If any number has remaining digits then that should be appended at last.

I do not want to convert int to string.

```
int CreateThirdNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{

}
```

So can anyone suggest me any solution to this problem?

Comment: You have algo where are you struck?

Comment: Hint: use the modulo operator and the division operator. this problem is rather easy to solve

Comment: This is simple.. Just need patience to reach the answer. You should first try yourself before posting.

Comment: [tag:business-logic]? Are you sure it's not [tag:homework]?

Comment: "I do not want to convert int to string" - why not?

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to convert int to string.

Why?

Without converting to string

> Use Modulus and Division operator.

With converting to string

> Convert them to string. Use .Substring() to extract and append value in a string. Convert appended string to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit that will give you a lead:

Say you have the number `2875`. First, you need to determine it's length, and then, *extract* the first digit

This can be easily calculated:

```
int iNumber = 2875;
int i = 10;
int iLength = 0;

while (iNumber % i <= iNumber){
    iLength++;
    i *= 10;
}

// iNumber is of length iLength, now get the first digit,
// using the fact that the division operator floors the result
int iDigit = iNumber / pow(10, iLength-1);
// Thats it!
```

Answer (score 1):

First a little advice: if you use `int` in C#, then the value in your example (2885725145) is bigger than `int.MaxValue;` (so in this case you should use `long` instead of `int`).
Anyway here is the code for your example, without strings.

```
        int i1 = 2875;
        int i2 = 852145;
        int i3 = 0;

        int i1len = (int)Math.Log10(i1) + 1;
        int i2len = (int)Math.Log10(i2) + 1;

        i3 = Math.Max(i1, i2) % (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Max(i1len, i2len) - Math.Min(i1len, i2len));

        int difference = (i1len - i2len); 
        if (difference > 0)
            i1 /= (int)Math.Pow(10, difference);
        else
            i2 /= (int)Math.Pow(10, -difference);

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(i1len, i2len); i++)
            {
            i3 += (i2 % 10) * (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Max(i1len, i2len) - Math.Min(i1len, i2len) + i * 2);
            i3 += (i1 % 10) * (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Max(i1len, i2len) - Math.Min(i1len, i2len) + i * 2 + 1);
            i1 /= 10;
            i2 /= 10;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to use strings (is it homework?). Anyway this is another possible solution:

```
    long CreateThirdNumber(long firstNumber, long secondNumber)
    {
        long firstN = firstNumber;
        long secondN = secondNumber;
        long len1 = (long)Math.Truncate(Math.Log10(firstNumber));
        long len2 = (long)Math.Truncate(Math.Log10(secondNumber));
        long maxLen = Math.Max(len1, len2);
        long result = 0;
        long curPow = len1 + len2 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxLen; i++)
        {
            if (len1 >= i)
            {
                long tenPwf = (long)Math.Pow(10, len1 - i);
                long firstD = firstN / tenPwf;
                firstN = firstN % tenPwf;
                result = result + firstD * (long)Math.Pow(10, curPow--);
            }
            if (len2 >= i)
            {

                long tenPws = (long)Math.Pow(10, len2 - i);
                long secondD = secondN / tenPws;
                result = result + secondD * (long)Math.Pow(10, curPow--);
                secondN = secondN % tenPws;
            }
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int first = 2875,second = 852145;
  unsigned int  third =0;
  int deci,evenodd ,tmp ,f_dec,s_dec;

  f_dec = s_dec =1;
  while(first/f_dec != 0 || second/s_dec != 0) {
    if(first/f_dec != 0) {
       f_dec *=10;

    }
    if( second/s_dec != 0) {
      s_dec *= 10;
    }

  }
  s_dec /=10; f_dec/=10;


  deci = s_dec*f_dec*10;


  evenodd =0;tmp =0;
  while(f_dec != 0 || s_dec !=0 )  {
    if(evenodd%2 == 0 && f_dec !=0 ) {
      tmp = (first/f_dec);
      first -=(tmp*f_dec);

      tmp*=deci;

      third+=tmp;
      f_dec/=10;
      deci/=10;
    }

    if(evenodd%2 != 0 && s_dec != 0) {
      tmp= (second/s_dec);
      second -=(tmp*s_dec);
      //printf("tmp:%d\n",tmp);

      tmp*=deci;

      third += tmp;
      s_dec/=10;
      deci/=10;
    }

    evenodd++;
  }
  printf("third:%u\ncorrct2885725145\n",third);
return 0;

}
```

output:

```
third:2885725145
corrct2885725145
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int CreateThirdNumber(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
    char first[11],second[11],third[21];
    char *p1=first, *p2=second, *p3=third;
    long long int ret;

    sprintf(first,  "%d", firstNumber);
    sprintf(second, "%d", secondNumber);
    while(1){
        if(*p1)
            *p3++=*p1++;
        if(*p2)
            *p3++=*p2++;
        if(*p1 == '\0' && *p2 == '\0')
            break;
    }
    *p3='\0';
    sscanf(third, "%lld", &ret);
    return ret;
}
int main(){
    int first = 2875;
    int second = 852145;
    long long int third;
    third = CreateThirdNumber(first, second);
    printf("%lld\n", third);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when first and second is 10-digit, not enough in int64(third)

Comment: The OP said he doesn't want to convert the numbers to strings

Comment: I thought it was meant as the final result. I think this method is in fact much easier.